# Solr get facet count after grouping

Tags: php, select, solr, facet

I have a solr index of jobs. Some jobs appear multiple times as they have multiple possible locations. To de-dupe, I group my query results by jobref.

I also have various partners that I receive jobs from. I want to provide a count of jobs per partner, AFTER grouping.

So far my (stripped down) code looks like:

```
// create client(solr) instance
$client = new Solarium\Client($solr_config);

// get a select query instance
$query = $client->createSelect();

// query for all, for now
$query->setQuery('*:*');

// get the facetset component
$facetSet = $query->getFacetSet();

// create a facet field instance and set options
$facetSet->createFacetField('partners')->setField('partner');

// BUNCH OF CODE THAT ADDS FILTER QUERIES ETC

// group jobs by jobref to avoid dupes (multiple locations)
$groupComponent = $query->getGrouping();
$groupComponent->addField('jobref');
$groupComponent->setLimit(1); // maximum number of items per group, only want the 1
$groupComponent->setNumberOfGroups(true);

// this executes the query and returns the result
$resultset = $client->select($query);

// get the grouped results
$groups = $resultset->getGrouping();

// get the facets
$facet = $resultset->getFacetSet()->getFacet('partners');
foreach ($facet as $value => $count) {
    echo $value . ' [' . $count . ']<br/>';
}

$jobs = array();

// TODO: does this have to be so complicated??
foreach ($groups as $groupKey => $fieldGroup) {
    $total_jobs = $fieldGroup->getNumberOfGroups();
    foreach ($fieldGroup as $valueGroup) {
        foreach ($valueGroup as $document) {
            array_push($jobs, $document);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I can see that my facets are calculated before the grouping, as if I add a filter query for a specific partner, my facet count is higher than my total results (grouped) count. How can I calculate/ get the facets after grouping??

This is using solarium php